# Manage Global Settings in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

What is the correct way to add global pieces of information that will be dynamically displayed in some parts of the site like the phone number, ..

These data may be changed from time to time. So, I want to make some centralized tweaking and avoid changing the code.

So far, I have found some solutions like global variables, adding entries in wp_topions table with phpMyAdmin and then retrieve them with WordPress functions.

I am still undecided about the most reliable method.